Why is my Data not storing in my radcombobox when I navigate away from the page?
In my asp.net application I have a radcombobox with checkboxes but whenever I select an item and navigate away from the page, the selection clears. Is there a property I might have missed?
I tried changing the viewstatemode property to no success.

Be it desktop windows, or web based?
When controls on a form (or even a webform) are filled out, if you leave that page, then it is destroyed, no longer in memory, and any and all values of controls are lost. This applies quite much to any development platform.
If you want the selected values to "persist" then you have to save the values BEFORE you leave that page. Often this suggests using a database to save the values on the form, or I suppose even saving the selections into some kind of persisted storage. Then when you return to the web page/form in question, your page load event will have to re-load and restore the values that were selected.
The above quite much applies to a check box, a text box, or just about any other controls you have on such forms. They don't by default "remember" anything at a all for you. If you "stay" on that page, then often ViewState will automatically persist the values for you, but after leaving such pages, then all of the control values are lost if you later return and re-load that given page in question.
I don't have the rad combo box, but say a simple ListView to select multiple cites like this:
Markup:
        <h3>Select Cites to display Hotels</h3>

        <asp:ListBox ID="lstCity" runat="server"
            DataTextField="City" Height="262px" 
            SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px">
        </asp:ListBox>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdViewHotels" runat="server" Text="View Hotels"
            OnClick="cmdViewHotels_Click"
            CssClass="btn"/>

And code to load above is this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Loadcombo()

    End If

End Sub

Sub Loadcombo()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City"

    lstCity.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    lstCity.DataBind()

    ' now set any selected city based on "saved" session() list

    If Not Session("CityChoice") Is Nothing Then

        Dim CityList As List(Of String) = Session("CityChoice")
        For Each OneCity As ListItem In lstCity.Items

            If CityList.Contains(OneCity.Text) Then
                OneCity.Selected = True
            End If
        Next

    End If


End Sub


Protected Sub cmdViewHotels_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' first save selected Cities into session()
    Dim CityList As New List(Of String)

    For Each OneCity As ListItem In lstCity.Items
        If OneCity.Selected Then
            CityList.Add(OneCity.Text)
        End If
    Next

    Session("CityChoice") = CityList
    Response.Redirect("CboTime.aspx")


End Sub

So, the result is now this:

Note how when I return back to the previous page, the values selected in the list box are re-set and re-loaded.
And the code on the target page to filter by the passed values? Well, we gain double use out of session, since I wanted to pass the selected list to the next page in question anyway. In other words, not only do we want to restore the selected values when we return, but we also use Session() to pass the selected list to the next web page in question for the GridView filter.
Hence this code:
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        LoadTable

    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadTable()

    Dim strSQL =
        "SELECT HotelName,City, Description FROM tblHotelsA "

    Dim strWhere As String = ""
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand()
    Dim CityList As List(Of String) = Session("CityChoice")

    For i = 0 To CityList.Count - 1
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= $","
        strWhere &= $"@P{i}"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add($"@P{i}", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CityList(i)
    Next

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strWhere = $" WHERE City IN ({strWhere})"
    End If
    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL & strWhere & " ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim dtHotels As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    GHotels.DataSource = dtHotels
    GHotels.DataBind()


End Sub

And the return to previous page to select more cities is this:
Protected Sub cmdBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Response.Redirect("SelectCity.aspx")

End Sub

So, note how before we navigate to the next web page, I process the selected items, and save to Session(). And note how when the page loads, I check for Session() and restore/re-select the items in the list.
So, be this a web page, a windows desktop program, something you write for Android, or whatever?
Controls on a given page don't out of the blue "remember" their settings when you leave such forms and load another form/web page. So, in effect, ViewState starts fresh and new when the web page first loads, and if you navigate away from that page, then ViewState of all controls on that page are lost. So, on first page load, a new ViewState is created for each page, and is disposed of when you leave the page. Hence, as above shows, if you wish controls to maintain their values after leaving the given web page, then you have to save and store such values in a location outside of that given page, since the page control values are displosed of, and even code behind valuables are also disposed of when you leave such pages.

Albert! Thank you for your detailed response. This form is writing to a database and when I make a selection I can see those selections in the data base but then the options are cleared when I return to the screen. This is an addition I'm making to an existing form (the other form items do not have this problem).
Do I need to do something specific in the databindings for the radcombobox? I'm thinking that it is having trouble reading back from the database when the page is loaded.

When you say "selections", then that suggests and means that if the user selects 2 or 5 values from the combobox, then say 5 rows must be written out someplace, right? I mean, if you allow multiple selecitons, then those multiple choices can't just be saved into one column in a database, but will result in multiple rows (one new row for each check box). I mean, you not EVEN shared that you using a database here, not shared your save code, so we really just making massive amounts of wild guessing here. In fact, in your comments that is the FIRST mention of even using a database!

All in all, the concept is going to be much the same as I outlined above. If the user makes multiple selections, then in place of saving out to session(), the same concpets appliy here. You will write out and save a row of data for each selection to some table in place of saving to session(). But, on page load, you need to do the two steps I have, first load up the choices into the combo box, and THEN process the list of selections you made into that combo box. So, the code either way will be VERY similar to above, just that you using a database in place of session().
